# Кто какую носит шляпу?

Tags: обсуждение, новогодние-шляпы

Заметили других участников в шляпе? Находите изображение профиля участника в шляпе необычным, веселым, элегантным? Пожалуйста, публикуйте ответ к этому вопросу со снимком экрана наиболее понравившихся вам изображений участников в головных уборах!

Несколько понравившихся мне, в качестве примера =)

[image: Андрей NOP]

[image: freim]

[image: Мелкий]

Comment: Чёрт, не о такой славе я мечтал! :D

Comment: @АндрейNOP На мой взгляд, у вас одна из самых потрясных шляп, которые я только видел :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP новый [виток славы](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/01/04/adios-to-winter-bash-2018/?cb=1) прилетел.

Answer (score 12):

Мне тут сказали, что шляпу надо только на голову надевать (хотя не понимаю, на хрена туалетная бумага на голове? Мысли вытирать? :))

Теперь претензий нет? :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кстати, в какой-то момент напялил бантик :) -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: одевал ... или надевал?

Comment: @älёxölüt Напялил. С такими тонкостями - к учительнице русского языка :) А то я уже пиццу-шляпу примерял - обуть на одну лапу... А теперь не знаю - по логике правильно - набуть?

Comment: Пиццу - наесть, конечно же!

Comment: Нет, набуть :) - см. картинку...

Comment: По-моему, картинка ничем не отличается от оригинала без "шляпы" :-D

Comment: @älёxölüt См. левую лапу. Как еще пиццу обуешь?

Comment: Лапу вижу, но (концептуально) ничего не изменилось. Только один большой красный кругляш стал маленьким, как и остальные три.

Comment: @älёxölüt Поскольку я старался только для вас - убираю :)

Comment: Кастрюлька на голове? :)

Comment: @Mikhailo Ну я же киевлянин...

Answer (score 8):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Помнится, я на MSE даже бан получил за надевание шляпы не на голову. Хотя нет, там был не бан, а снятие шляпы с предупреждением так не делать, иначе отключат шляпы для меня перманентно. Собственно, в этом году и не участвую в этом балагане даже.

Comment: @älёxölüt, oO серьезно?)) и такое бывает))))

Comment: у Harry я так понимаю не непристойность, а как ... билетер что ли))))

Comment: [Ссылка на удалённый вопрос](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304844/339911). [Скриншот](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL5v1.png), для тех у кого нет 10K на MSE.

Comment: @älёxölüt, мда ... зато делать из рулона туалетки шапку - это норма)

Comment: Кто-то пытался ещё оскорбиться шапкой из меноры, но, видимо, оказался недостаточно настойчив.

Comment: Не на голову? Мне тоже ждать бана?)

Comment: А что, можно что-то делать, чтобы надеть шляпу не автоматически?

Comment: @avp нажмите "показать инструменты" под изображением

Comment: @cppquestionsm спасибо!

Comment: @älёxölüt Очень даже веселая ава у тебя получилась :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ маску надо одевать на лицо :)

Comment: @Danis надевать!

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, маски надоели в реальной жизни))) А шапки пока не нравятся)

Answer (score 5):

Сменил очки и отвечаю под музыку с [retrowave.ru](http://retrowave.ru/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

А я их периодически меняю, их же не просто так дают, а для настроения!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

*Шляпник* (на английском зовут *Hatter* - он же *Болванщик*), а хотя Джига-Дрыга не течет в крови, и вроде бы не безумен  Будем вводить в моду синие цилиндры.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Я уже постил [ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320462/403480) на подобный вопрос на всеобщей <strike>помойке</strike> Мете.

Так как у меня один глаз(к счастью, не в реальной жизни), то я не могу носить очки, маску ниндзя и т.д. Но у меня еще куча шляп!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]